# Fortran - combinations of sums and products

Tags: loops, fortran, combinations

This is program. Its essence is as follows. There are two arrays of dimension 2 to 3. I need to find all the possible combinations of sums and products according to the filter E_max. Can you please tell how to write more compact nested loops, i.e., that if I have 10 columns do not paint the 10 nested loops ? Help me, please.

```
program f_
implicit none
integer E_max, i, j, k, i1, j1, k1, l
real  f1, f2, oldp, oldp1, oldp2, oldp_1, oldp_2, p1, p2, p3, p
real(8), allocatable, dimension(:, :) :: F, ener
real(8), allocatable, dimension(:) :: E_vib, f_1
allocate (F(2,3), E_vib(3), f_1(3), ener(2,3))

open( unit=10, file= 'File.txt', status='old')
do j = 1, 2     
read(10,*) (f(j,k),k=1,3) 
end do 
201 j=j-1
close(unit=10, status='keep')
003 format(f25.20,1x,\)

open( unit=10, file= 'fileen.txt', status='old')
do j = 1, 2     
read(10,*) (ener(j,k),k=1,3) 
end do 
205 j=j-1
close(unit=10, status='keep')
004 format(f25.20,1x,\)

E_max = 4
do i = 1, 2
 oldp = ener(i,1)
 p1 = f(i,1)

  if (oldp > E_max) then
 goto 1
end if
1   continue 

do j = 1, 2
 oldp1 = ener(j,2)
 p2 = f(j,2)
   if (oldp1 + oldp > E_max) then
    goto 2
   end if
   2 continue 

   do k = 1, 2
  oldp2 = ener(k,3)
  p3 = f(k,3)
    if (oldp2 + oldp1 + oldp > E_max) then
     goto 5
    end if

  oldp_1 = oldp + oldp1 + oldp2 
  p = p1*p2*p3

  write (*,*) 'i=', i , 'j=', j,'k=', k, oldp_1, p
  5 continue  
    end do
   end do
end do

deallocate (F, E_vib, f_1, ener)
end program
```

Comment: http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/programming-with-reason-why-is-goto-bad/228200966

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably more of an extended comment than an answer but here goes.

One thing you could do to make your program more compact is to carefully think about the logic of blocks such as

```
   if (oldp1 + oldp > E_max) then
    goto 2
   end if
   2 continue
```

This block of code has precisely no effect on the program and can be deleted without any effect.  A really smart compiler might already be doing that for you but, just in case you don't have such a smart compiler, you could help it by deleting the code yourself.

There are other places where the logic of the program is very difficult to follow and, to be honest, I have given up.  Do yourself a favour, replace all the `goto`s in the program with their modern equivalents (think `exit`, think `cycle`), eliminate all the `continue` statements (think `end`).  Once you've tided all that up it might be possible to figure out the answer to the question you have asked.

Comment: Thank you very much. I would think and try to solve the problem.